# Is it possible to read form data in servlet with out name or Id

Tags: jakarta-ee

Is it possible to read form data in servlet with out name or Id?
Does the browser automatically assign default name/id to input field while submitting form?

Answer (score 0):

It´s possible.

In a jsp you can write a param like this:

```
<html:hidden property="action" styleId="action"/>
<input type="hidden" name="validate"/>
```

the first param it written in struts and the second in a Web proyect.

From a servlet, you have access to the current HttpServletRequest request. In this request you can invoke the method request.getParameter("action") and request.getParameter("validate") and it returns a String.

I hope this help you.
Marcos.